# OrbisGIS CTS error transform EPSG coordinates java

Tags: java, coordinates, transform, gis

I have and error with CTS transformation coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
CRSFactory cRSFactory = new CRSFactory();
RegistryManager registryManager = cRSFactory.getRegistryManager();
registryManager.addRegistry(new EPSGRegistry());

CoordinateReferenceSystem crs1 = null;
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs2 = null;

try{
  crs1 = (CoordinateReferenceSystem) cRSFactory.getCRS("EPSG:25831");
  crs2 = (CoordinateReferenceSystem) cRSFactory.getCRS("EPSG:4326");
}catch (CRSException ie){
  System.err.println("CRSException: " + ie.getMessage());
}

GeodeticCRS sourceGCRS = (GeodeticCRS) crs1;
GeodeticCRS targetGCRS = (GeodeticCRS) crs2;
Set<CoordinateOperation> coordOps = null;

try{
  coordOps = CoordinateOperationFactory.createCoordinateOperations(sourceGCRS, targetGCRS);
}catch (CoordinateOperationException ie){
  System.err.println("CoordinateOperationException: " + ie.getMessage());
}

parts =  new String[2];
parts = parts2;

System.out.println("latitud: " + parts[0]);
System.out.println("longitud: " + parts[1]);

double[] coord = new double[2];
boolean isValidDouble = false;

try{
  coord[0] = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
  coord[1] = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
  isValidDouble = true;
}catch(NumberFormatException  eo){
  isValidDouble = false;
}

double[] dd = new double[2];

if (coordOps.size() != 0 && isValidDouble == true) {
// Test each transformation method (generally, only one method is available)
//System.out.println("POINT (" + coord[0] + " " + coord[1] + ")");
  for (CoordinateOperation op : coordOps) {
    // Transform coord using the op CoordinateOperation from crs1 to crs2
    try{
      dd  = op.transform(coord);                                    
    }catch (IllegalCoordinateException ie){                                     
      System.err.println("IllegalCoordinateException: " + ie.getMessage());
    }catch (CoordinateOperationException ie){                                       
      System.err.println("CoordinateOperationException: " + ie.getMessage());
    }                                   
  }
}

System.out.println(getGeometry() + " ("  + dd[1] + " " + dd[0] + ")");
```

Here my outputs:

latitud: 932178.5916381918
longitud: 4592070.597899773 
Point (6.253901743245093E-5 -1.4884056282499645)

Expected outputs:

latitud: 932178.5916381918
longitud: 4592070.597899773 
Point (8.16641764158 41.3640864715)

PD: I tried to change lat/long for long/lat, is the example, and vice versa. Don't change nothing.

Anyone have the answer?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code worked fine for me to convert to EPSG:4326 to EPSG:31467.Verified the outputs using https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=4326&t_srs=31467. was breaking my head with geoTools with endless exceptions for a day .Thanks  a lot!